# Query the IP of the interface that will be used for a connection to a certain target

Tags: c, linux, routes, network-programming, ip-address

I have a Linux server with multiple interfaces. Each interface has an IP and network. Also there is a default route and other routes in a routing table so that connections to certain networks go over one or the other interface. Of course, connections initiated by any programm going to an IP in the same network as one of the intefaces of the server will go over that interface.

Given a target IP that a programm on that server is going to connect to: Is there an API to retrieve the IP address of that local interface that will be used?

Or alternatively: Once an connection has just been initiated to a certain IP, how can I get exactly that local IP address of the server that is most appropriate?
Is that available?

I don't want to write the routing logic again.

Example:
eth0: 192.168.1.10/24
eth1: 10.1.1.20/24
default gw: 192.168.1.1
additional static route:
to 10.2.0.0/16 via 10.1.1.1

Now if a programm initiates an UDP connection to 1.2.3.4, it would use eth0 and the appropritate IP I want to query would be 192.168.10.
Now if a programm initiates an UDP connection to 10.2.55.66, it would use eth1 and the appropritate IP I want to query would be 10.1.1.20.
Now if a programm initiates an UDP connection to 10.1.1.9, it would use eth1 and the appropritate IP I want to query would be 10.1.1.20.

The reason for this question is that I want to modify the snmp-trap sending programm to put the right address in the agentField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFSv4 `mount` does something very similar when the local IP address is not specified via the `clientaddr` parameter. It has to obtain the local IP address the remote NFS server can connect to, even when there are multiple interfaces on the local machine.

It does this by creating an UDP datagram socket, binding to local addresses, `connect()`ing to the remote machine, then querying the local IP address that would be used for the outgoing packets using `getsockname()`. Because UDP is a connectionless protocol, no data is sent via the wire at all; this uses only the local routing tables to determine the local IP address bound to the socket.

See [utils/mount/network.c:nfs_callback_address()](http://git.linux-nfs.org/?p=steved/nfs-utils.git;a=blob;f=utils/mount/network.c;hb=HEAD#l1153) at [Linux-NFS git repository](http://git.linux-nfs.org/?p=steved/nfs-utils.git;a=summary) for the implementation. It uses [utils/mount/network.c:nfs_ca_sockname()](http://git.linux-nfs.org/?p=steved/nfs-utils.git;a=blob;f=utils/mount/network.c;hb=HEAD#l1077) to obtain the address, and [utils/mount/network.c:nfs_ca_gai()](http://git.linux-nfs.org/?p=steved/nfs-utils.git;a=blob;f=utils/mount/network.c;hb=HEAD#l1127) to check if the address family is supported on the local machine (so that it won't return a local address (callback address in NFS terms) using an address family, say IPv6, that is not supported on the local machine).

Yes, this will fail if the *machine-internal* routing changes after the above is done -- that is, you modify the routing table by hand to use another interface for that destination IP address.  It is not really a problem, because that will usually break (hang until timeout) all existing connections anyway, because they are bound to the wrong local IP address, and the kernel cannot just switch that from under the processes.  In other words, if you do that, you must expect connection breakage anyway.

Routing changes outside the local machine are not affected. It should be obvious why: the original UDP connection test did not reach outside the machine, only to local routing tables. Any routing outside the machine itself (including next hop, or gateway addresses external to the machine, in the local routing table) does not cause any breakage, and does not change the results obtained using the above procedure.

I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

*Is there an API to retrieve the IP address of that local interface that will be used?*

I don't believe so.  It would be inherently racy, anyway - the routing table could change between the time when you queried that API and the time you actually made the connection.

*Or alternatively: Once an connection has just been initiated to a certain IP, how can I get exactly that local IP address of the server that is most appropriate? Is that available?*

This you can do - once you have a connected socket, `getsockname()` will tell you the local address of the socket, which includes both the IP address and port number.